# Ubuntu 14.04 won't boot from hdd

Tags: 14.04, boot, hard-drive

I created a live USB on my laptop from a live Ubuntu disc, plugged it into my desktop and installed it to my 500gb hard drive. When I boot my pc, however, the hard drive is not listed as a bootable device. What can I do? 
EDIT: I disabled 2.2TB infinity and changed boot priority and that fixed it.

Comment: what do you mean with the hard drive not being listed, do you mean in your bios?

Comment: did you change your disk back to the default boot entry in your bios?

Answer (score 0):

Look in your BIOS and see if it is the first boot priority. Make sure to unplug the installation media if you haven't done so already. You might have to reinstall it if it shows up in the BIOS, but if it doesn't show up, you need a new hard drive.